# Linksys WRT110 router: do reserved IPs need to be in IP Address Range?

Tags: dhcp, router

I'm using a [Linksys WRT110](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/1224639048471/WRT110-EU_V10_UG_81201A-WEB.pdf) RangePlus Wireless Router. My question is: do IPs reserved under DHCP Reservation need to be within the IP Address Range?

I'd like to reserve a consistent IP for my laptop. But if I reserve an IP within the IP Address Range, it seems like it will sometimes assign that IP to a different device. And if I reserve an IP outside of the range, it doesn't always assign it to me even when it's free. However, the behavior seems inconsistent, so I'm not sure what the rule is.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to reserve a consistent IP for my laptop.

Great!  That's what the reservation is for.

> But if I reserve an IP within the IP Address Range, it seems like it
>   will sometimes assign that IP to a different device.

Just as when you reserve a table with a restaurant, they (the router) hold it for the person (computer) that it is reserved for, rather than giving it to another patron (computer)

> And if I reserve an IP outside of the range, it doesn't always assign
>   it to me even when it's free. However, the behavior seems
>   inconsistent, so I'm not sure what the rule is.

I can't really help here; I'm not sure why that would work sometimes rather than never.  Perhaps your computer is simply being assigned a different (functional) IP address since the reservation is invalid?

Comment: So you're saying my router is like this [car rental service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-brgkkjnHc)? 

Answer (score 0):

<s>Yes, DHCP Reservations need to be in the DHCP IP Address Range. While I am not familiar with that particular Linksys router, I have used many other Linksys models and they have all worked the same, meaning it *should* give you an error when you try to reserve one outside the range</s>. But you did not show us the DHCP Reservation list. While you can manually add a device, I would suggest making sure the laptop is connected, then adding it from the list of connected devices.

Comment: That would be an incredibly annoying decision and I personally have never encountered a router with that limitation. Generally, the dynamically-assigned range and the statically-assigned range don't overlap because otherwise it's virtually impossible to administer them. Having a range that is both automatically *and* manually assigned is bad practice. How does the human doing the manual assignment coordinate with the machine doing the automatic assignment?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz DHCP Reservations and Static IP assignments are two different things. And you are correct, that would be impossible to manage.

Comment: A DHCP Reservation is a form of static IP assignment. The IP is assigned by a human once and never changes and is in no sense dynamic. How do you manage that if you're assigning them from the same pool the router is assigning dynamic IP addresses from? That would be awful.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because it is the **router** that is actually doing the assignment. The laptop is still set to DHCP; you have told the router through **its** configuration that when this device connects, always give it this IP address. The "reserved" IP address is reserved by the router, so it does not give that IP to any other client. It uses the MAC address to know which device. If, on the other hand, the **user** assigns a static IP address on a device, it **must** be outside the DHCP range, so that there is no conflict with DHCP assigned addresses.

Comment: Not sure how that's responsive to what I said. A human has to pick the address to be reserved and if they don't know what addresses the router may be using, it's awfully hard for them to do that. How the static IP address is communicated to the device doesn't affect the administrative issue of a human having to assign it one. For example, I commonly install security equipment that is difficult to assign a static IP address to on the device, so I assign one in my router. It would annoying if the router might give a dynamic DHCP assignment right inside the range I'm using for reservations.

Comment: I wouldn't want my devices being .7, .8. and then some other kind of device gets .9, so when I add another security device they're discontiguous. But what can I do to stop that? Such a router's DHCP reservation feature would be nearly useless. You might as well assign static IP address so that they can be sensible and not randomly distributed along with non-reserved devices.

Comment: The addresses the router is using are the ones in the DHCP IP Address Range, as shown in the OP's screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107118/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-cb-ron).